# Error code 1703 with no message and options and forced reboot after pressing OK

Tags: windows-installer

What could cause this dialog to popup with no message?
The usual message should state something like: "You must restart your computer to apply these changes. Press Yes to reboot now....press NO to restart later"
After pressing OK, the system just reboots with no warning.

I can't replicate that issue on my system, just got a customer with that issue.

[image: 1703 error dialog]

Comment: Not sure, have you checked for malware on that box? What is that green icon? Looks like some sort of printer software. What software is that? Can it be uninstalled?

Comment: Nope, our software ran fine after the reboot, so we didn't care. Still curious what could be the cause.